# PHP, XML element path

Tags: php, xml

Hey I am trying to get viewers from XML file. Problem is in path cuz other paths were working for me. I guess problem is because it's element? `<media:statistics views="131"/>`

```php
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCH7Hj6l_xDmbyvjQOA5Du0g";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$views = $xml->entry[0]->children('media', true)->group[0]->children('media', true)->community[0]->children('media', true)->attributes('statistics');
echo $views;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the views by using instead of using `->attributes('statistics')` use the statistics property first, and from that, get the views from the attributes:

```
->statistics->attributes()->views;
```

The code could look like:

```
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCH7Hj6l_xDmbyvjQOA5Du0g";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$views = $xml->entry[0]->children('media', true)->group[0]->children('media', true)->community[0]->children('media', true)->statistics->attributes()->views;
echo $views;
```

Output

```
131
```